# Windows Authentication stops working on project published to live server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project, I use windows authentication for auditing purposes (rather than logging in), so I know who has made certain changes. The variable used to access the usernames is `User.Identity.Name` and I have also made sure to set up my web.config file correctly:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
 </system.web>
```

This all worked fine, but I have recently published my project to a live server and for some reason it has stopped seeing the usernames (it now logs a blank string instead), even though it worked on my local machine. Any idea what I may have missed to make this work on a live server? It still works with no problems on my local machine.

Comment: Is anonymous authentication disabled in IIS?

Comment: You need to disabled anonymous authentication, and enable windows authentication on the server (IIS).

Comment: @PaulAbbott That fixed it thanks. You want to write the answer in the answer place so I can credit you?